# What can be the cause for error while building ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

While I build my solution it shows following error:

> 'System.Web.HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'RequestContext' and no extension method 'RequestContext' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What dll or reference I am missing!

Code:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            string methodName = "";
            if (request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["methodName"] != null)
            {
                methodName = request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["methodName"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                methodName = request.RawUrl.Substring(request.RawUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            }

            //if form post was made way to get values
            //context.Request.Form["firstName"]; //parameter key
            string json = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ServiceProcesser process = new ServiceProcesser(typeof(AspxCommerce.AdminNotification.AdminNotificationController), json, methodName);
            var response = process.Invoke();

            if (response != null)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(new { d = response }));
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(new { d = "" }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            var resp = new { d = ex.Message.ToString() };
            context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(resp));
        }
    }
```

For full source you can explore my github repo:
https://github.com/Milstein/Ratamata

Comment: Post the code which produces this error

Comment: Please show your code that declares your RequestContext object.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpRequest.RequestContext` was not introduced until .NET version 4, as can be seen in the "Version Information" section of the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requestcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

My guess is that you're using .NET 2.0 or 3.5, so you don't have access to that property.  You can check this by right-clicking on your website project, choosing **Properties** from the dropdown, and checking the **Target framework** option on the **Application** tab.

Comment: It's already build with .NET 4 framework would you please look at my github repo:
https://github.com/Milstein/Ratamata

Comment: Very few people are going to go fork your repo just to help you solve your problem. Believe it or not, some people don't even use git.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case it was due to the wrong assembly that has been referred (yes, a silly mistake..) . 
Which was `*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll*`.

Then I installed ***Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core*** package using **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core** command.

Then it will refer `*~\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll*`.